# Glob lists files, file_exists() says they don't exist

Tags: php

I've got a bit of a strange issue related to `file_exists()` and `glob()`. The latter lists all the files in this specific directory no problem, but if I iterate over the file paths and call `file_exists()` on them it returns false.

My first reaction was that this was a problem with permissions, but I've ran

`sudo chmod -R 766 ./directoryName`

so that PHP will have read access at the least. Still no difference.

I've read a couple of other questions on here that mentioned safe mode potentially being an issue, but I've verified that my PHP (`PHP Version 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10`) isn't running in safe mode.

This is my `ls -la` output in the directory in question...

```
drwxrw-rw-  6 user     user      4096 2012-08-04 16:15 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 user     user      4096 2012-08-04 12:42 ..
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user       141 2012-07-25 20:43 AppCache.php
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user      1982 2012-08-04 10:54 AppKernel.php
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user       474 2012-07-25 20:43 autoload.php
-rwxrw-rw-  1 www-data user     47590 2012-08-06 20:01 bootstrap.php.cache
drwxrwxrw-+ 3 user     user      4096 2012-08-06 20:24 cache
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user      1643 2012-08-06 20:01 check.php
drwxrw-rw-  2 user     user      4096 2012-08-04 12:41 config
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user       794 2012-07-25 20:43 console
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user        13 2012-07-25 20:43 .htaccess
drwxrwxrw-+ 2 user     user      4096 2012-08-06 20:25 logs
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user      1327 2012-07-25 20:43 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxrw-rw-  3 user     user      4096 2012-08-04 12:41 Resources
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user     24240 2012-08-06 20:01 SymfonyRequirements.php
-rwxrw-rw-  1 user     user       727 2012-07-25 20:43 upgrade.php
```

In my index script, I'm doing the following as a very basic test...

```
$files = glob('/path/to/directory/*.cache');
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo $file . ':';
    var_dump(file_exists($file));
    echo '<br>';
}
```

which outputs the following...

```
/path/to/directory/bootstrap.php.cache:
boolean false
```

If I create a script and run it from command line, the `file_exists()` call returns `true` as expected.

Comment: Read access and `766` might not be enough - IIRC, you need the `x` permission to be able to "look into" directories. I would change it to `755` and see what happens.

Comment: bingo! add that as an answer and I'll accept it, cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC, without the `+x` permission bit, you won't be able to read into directories, which could be the source of the problem.

Changing the permission mask to `755` instead of `766` should give PHP read and execute privileges, which should solve the problem.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 ./directoryName
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, your permissions look plenty permissible, but I have a feeling it's because the owner is "user".

To test, try changing the permissions to whatever the name of the php user is, you can find this with:

`echo whoami();`

Then check your index.php

If that's the case, you could create a group for your files which has both 'user' and the php user (usually 'daemon' from what I understand)

cheers!